# Finding the quadrature variance of a superposition of squeezed coherent states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-information

How do you find the quadrature variance of a state $$\lvert x\rangle =\lvert a,b\rangle +\lvert a,-b\rangle$$ where $\lvert a,b\rangle = D(a) S(b) \lvert 0\rangle$?

$\lvert x\rangle$ is a superposition of squeezed coherent states.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the expression for $S(z)$ we have:

$\hat{S(b)} = e^{b\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}^\dagger - b^* \hat{a}\hat{a}}$

Through the following BCH formula:

$e^BAe^{-B} = A + [B,A] + \frac{1}{2!} [B,[B,A]] ...$

We can see that, since $ [\hat{a}, \hat{a}^\dagger]=1:$
$\hat{S(b)} \hat{a} \hat{S(b)}^\dagger = \hat{a}cosh(r) + \hat{a}^\dagger e^{i\theta} sinh(r)$

And a simmilar expression for $\hat{a}^\dagger$.

We can also do the same thing for $\hat{D(a)} = e^{a\hat{a}^\dagger - a^* \hat{a}}$ . Here the commutator [B,A] will be a constant and the series will have only two non-zero terms.

$\hat{D(a)} \hat{a} \hat{D(a)}^\dagger = \hat{a} + a$

Then we use the unitarity of these operators to achieve:

$\hat{a} \hat{D(a)} \hat{S(b)} \lvert 0 \rangle = \hat{D(a)} (\hat{a} + a) \hat{S(b)} \lvert 0 \rangle$

$= a\hat{D(a)} \hat{S(b)}  \lvert 0 \rangle + e^{i\theta} sinh(r) \hat{D(a)} \hat{S(b)}  \hat{a}^\dagger  \lvert 0 \rangle $

...

We have expressions for how $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^\dagger$ act on $ \lvert a,b\rangle$:

$$ \hat{a} \lvert a,b\rangle = a\lvert a,b\rangle + e^{i\theta} \sinh(r)D(a) S(b) \hat{a}^\dagger \lvert 0\rangle $$

$$ \hat{a}^\dagger \lvert a,b\rangle = a^* \lvert a,b\rangle + \cosh(r)D(a) S(b) \hat{a}^\dagger \lvert 0\rangle $$

...

Using the definitions of quadrature, and their respective variances:

$$\sigma^2_q = \langle q^2\rangle_x - \langle q\rangle^2_x = \frac{1}{2} \left[\langle x \rvert (\hat{a}^2 + \hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger} +\hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}  + \hat{a}^{\dagger2})  \lvert x \rangle - \langle x \rvert (\hat{a} + \hat{a}^{\dagger}) \lvert x \rangle ^2\right] $$

Comment: Where can I find the derivation of how the annihilation and creation operators act on the squeezed coherent states.?

Comment: I did this as an exercise not long ago, so I don't have sources but I'll try to outline the proof in my answer.

Comment: I am not getting a sensible answer I need to prove that the quadrature variance for this state is less than the minimum uncertainty state, but I'm not getting that. If its possible can u send me photos of ur solution to my mail id aravind.ar.h@gmail.com.  How does the ladder operator^2 act on these states. The algebra is getting really messy and complicated and I'm ending up with waay too many terms. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about my answer if u have photos of ur solution It'd be a huge help if u could send the photos

Comment: I get the variance as negative which is obviously not right

Comment: I did not solve this to the end, but I'll try. As for the ladder ops.^2, make one operator act on the right and one on the left. Since $\langle x \rvert \hat{a} = (\hat{a}^\dagger \lvert x \rangle)^\dagger$, then: $\langle x \rvert \hat{a} \hat{a} \lvert x \rangle = (\hat{a}^\dagger \lvert x \rangle)^\dagger \hat{a} \lvert x \rangle$, and that is given by the expressions above. You can do the same for $\hat{a}^{\dagger 2}$ and other combinations. P.S.: If you are not familiar with that, I define $(\lvert x \rangle)^\dagger = \langle x \rvert$.

Comment: But now that you said that you just want to prove this is smaller that something else, maybe there is a smarter way of doing it without calculating the full expression, but I can't see what it is. What do you mean by 'minimum uncertainty state'? Is it a Heissenberg uncertainty?

Comment: The coherent state is a minimum uncertainty state the quadrature variances would be equal and minimum and equal to 1/4

Comment: What about the action of the ladder operator on |a, - b> can we replace b by - b in the above expression??

Comment: Don't u need to normalise this state before finding its variance?

Comment: To your first question, no. Remember the definition of these states through the $D_\alpha$ and $S_z$ operators. Changing z to -z gives a different operator in general. To your second question, yes, the states need to be normalized. Since D and S are unitary and the vacuum is normalized you need only to divide $\vert x \rangle $ by $\sqrt{2}$.